# Aerospike secondery index on map

Tags: nosql, aerospike

I have a question about Aerospike DB , and secondry indexes.

I have set of students , and each student (record key is StudentId), 
has a map (bin) , that consists of `<CourseId ,Grade>`.

I want to select only students that participated specific coursesIds .
How can I do it ?
Should I add secondry index on the map? Using UDF?

Thanks.

Comment: ", that consists of ." - consists of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two approaches - one with secondary indexes, and one without (just key-value operations using the primary index).

**Without Secondary Indexes**

Let's actually assume you have three types at your application, each in its own set in Aerospike - `courses`, `students`, `roster`. The course object holds information about the course, the student objects hold information about the student.
The `roster` objects have the same key as the course, or maybe a composite *courseID|semester*. The course should have a bin *students* which holds a list of student IDs. To get the students of a course you get the `roster` record, then turn its list of student keys into a single batch-read operation against `students`.

Of course you could also collapse this and just have two sets - `courses` and `students` and keep the list of course students as a bin in the course object. No need for a many-to-one join here, since you have the [list](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html) and [map](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-map.html) complex [data types](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/data-types.html) to work with.

If you wanted to do more complex queries without a secondary index, you can apply a [predicate filter](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html) onto a scan of the `courses` set (See an [example](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-java/blob/master/examples/src/com/aerospike/examples/QueryPredExp.java) of using the Java client this way).

**With Secondary Indexes**

You can add a bin *in-course* to the student objects, with its value being a list of course IDs (meaning that you can easily get the course object from the ID). You can build a [secondary index over that list](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/query.html#secondary-index-key-data-type) of course IDs. To get the student's courses you get the student object by its key, and look at the *in-course* bin. To get all the students in a specific course, run a secondary index query over that bin of the records in the `students` set.

You can apply a predicate filter to the records found by this secondary index query, to further filter the students by other criteria.

Comment: Hi Ronen, Thanks for your detailed comment.
   PredExp works fine with the scenario I described.
   I have another scenario, with a query on the courses map.
   But now I want to use contains instead of equals for specific CourseId.
   I mean, select only courses that their courseId exists in ListOfCourses.
   I did not find a relevant method in PredExp.
   Is it possible with PredExp?
  
   Thanks!

Comment: I also saw an option to use MAPKEYS with filter. But it also doesn't support my scenario .

Comment: [PredExp](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/query/PredExp.html) has 'list contains', 'map keys contain', and 'map values contain' operations. The Java client's API is hosted here: https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java

Comment: Do you mean mapKeyIterateOr / mapValIterateOr ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. List, mapKeys, mapValues have and/or iterators for picking records who contain a specific element (courseID) in those.

Comment: Thanks Ronen, 
But all those methods get as input only one String,
I want to pass a List of courseIds.

Comment: Click on the method, and you'll get examples of how to use it. The 'string' is for the key name.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for your patience:)
Correct me if I wrong ,
But in the example of mapKeyIterateOr they compared between mapBin("m") keys , 
to integerValue=7. 
And I want to find matches between mapBin("m"), to List of values.(without Itereate the list)  
Is it possible?

Comment: At this point it's a completely different question, so open it as a separate ones. A chain of comments doesn't make a good answer. I'm still not sure if you're asking for "get all the courses from Aerospike whose course ID is in a list of course IDs" or "get all the students taking ALL the courses in the following list of course IDs". Can you open a separate question? These two questions can refer to each other.

Comment: Yes for sure . Thanks